# Issue credential for schema created by others

Tags: hyperledger, aries

I'm trying to setup multitenancy for hyperledger py cloud agent.

I enabled multi tenancy created subwallet, but when trying to issue credential for user subwallet i get WalletItemNotFound. This credential definition wasn't created by user wallet but I added it with aries agent's

`/schemas/<schemaId>/write_record`
and
`/credential-definitions/<schemaId>/write_record`

still they are not recognized when trying to issue credential, any thoughts?